# Slider which can load images around itself

Tags: slider

I'll start with visualization:

[Slider visualization!](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwQPHxVeoc90T0dRb3R5WTU3TUE/edit)

So the point is that I want to have slider that can load different images around itself specific for each slide.

For example:

Slide 1 load around slider images 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 which are clickable.
Slide 2 does the same with pictures 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12.
Etc...

Is this is even possible?

I tought about two sliders working together but I don't know where to start with something like that and how to make one stylized like that (green items).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution to use 2 or more synced sliders and it could be easly done with [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) and function from their github forum:

```
$(function(){
      var slider1 = $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
        auto: false,
        mode: 'fade',
        pager: false,
        preloadImages: 'visible'
      });
      var slider2 = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        mode: 'fade',
        preloadImages: 'visible',
        onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
          slider1.goToSlide(newIndex);
        }
      });
    });
```

Big slider in the middle will be regualr slider and those little once could be carousels synced with the big one.

And if you want synchronize more then one just make copy from slider1, rename it and add `sliderX.goToSlide(newIndex);`